# Inserting and finding nodes - Linked Lists in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

1) I'm still trying to wrap my head around how linked lists work in c++. Currently I'm trying to insert a new node in between other nodes. Although I'm able to add the desired node, anything after that new node seems to be deleted once I print it:

```
void InsertNode(int pos, int val) {
        Node *n = new Node();
        n->data = val;

        Node *pnt = head;

        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
            pnt = pnt->next;
        }

        pnt->next = n;

        DisplayList();
    }
```

2) And then I want to be able to create another operation that can search for an element in the list and output its position (if it exists). However from what I know so far I don't see how I can compare a value that I want to find to an element in a list.

Here's what I'd imagine it would look like, but I know the if statement isn't valid.

```
void SearchElement(int val) {
    Node *list = head;

    int i = 0;
    while (list) {
        list = list->next;
        i++;

        if (list == val) { cout << "The value is at position: " << i << endl; }
    }

    //print statement saying it doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append the rest of the list to n before you insert the new node:

```
n->next = pnt->next;
pnt->next = n;
```

For the second question: Your value is in list->data.

```
int i = 0;
while (list) {
    if (list->data == val) { 
        cout << "The value is at position: " << i << endl; 
        break; 
    }
    list = list->next;
    i++;        
}
```

Comment: Thanks, solved my question for part two. However for part one the  "new" node is actually replacing another instead of being added to the list.  Any suggestions?

Comment: corrected my answer: it has to be n->next = pnt->next;